# Non-exhaustive patterns in function buildTree' Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, tuples

I use function that returns tuples. But when I try to run the function it gives me an exception:  Non-exhaustive patterns in function.

```
buildTree' :: String -> Tree  -> (String,Tree)
buildTree' (x:xs)  currenttree 
|null (x:xs) = ("empty", currenttree)
|isDigit x && ( take 1  xs == ['+'] ||  take 1 xs == ['-'])= buildTree' xs (Node [x] Empty Empty)
|isDigit x = buildTree' newstring1 (snd (buildrecursion (getminiexpr(x:xs)) Empty))
|elem x "+-" = buildTree' newstring (buildTree2 currenttree newtree [x])
    where newtree = (snd (buildrecursion (getminiexpr xs) Empty))
          newstring = drop (length(getminiexpr xs)) xs
          newstring1 = drop (length(getminiexpr (x:xs))) (x:xs)


getminiexpr :: String -> String 
getminiexpr input = takeWhile ( \y -> y /= '+' && y /= '-') input
```

Comment: It really looks like you are doing *too* much in your functions. You should really try to implement *simpler* functions that each do a very simple thing. You can compile with `-Wall` and Haskell will show what the problem is. At first sight, it looks like you did not cover `buildTree []`.

Comment: The `null (x:xs)` guard doesn't do what I expect you think it does. `x:xs` is a pattern that can never be matched by an empty list. You need a separate pattern for `buildTree' [] currentTree` to cover this case. In general, pattern matching is more idiomatic in Haskell than using guards - but guards can do more so you do need them sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

`(x:xs)` is not an arbitrary list/string, it is a non empty list/string whose head is `x` and whose tail is `xs`. Hence

```
buildTree' (x:xs)  currenttree 
   ...
```

only handles *non empty* lists. Compiling with `-Wall` would warn that the empty list case is missing. So, you need:

```
buildTree' [] currenttree = ...
buildTree' (x:xs)  currenttree 
   ...
```

Adapting your code, we can remove the `null` guard:

```
buildTree' [] currenttree = ("empty", currenttree)
buildTree' (x:xs)  currenttree 
   | isDigit x && ( take 1  xs == ['+'] ||  take 1 xs == ['-'])= buildTree' xs (Node [x] Empty Empty)
   ...
```

Similarly, the `take` checks need more than the head `x` of the list. You can write, instead:

```
buildTree' [] currenttree = ("empty", currenttree)
buildTree' (x1:x2:xs)  currenttree 
   | isDigit x1 && ( x2 == '+' || x2 == '-') = buildTree' (x2:xs) (Node [x1] Empty Empty)
   ...
```

or even

```
buildTree' [] currenttree = ("empty", currenttree)
buildTree' (x1:x2:xs)  currenttree 
   | isDigit x1 && (x2 `elem` "+-") = buildTree' (x2:xs) (Node [x1] Empty Empty)
   ...
```

I have no idea about whether your logic is correct.